# Find frequency of words in a column in Google Sheets and lookup another value from a different column using formulae

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have 2 columns of data in a Google Sheet. Column1 is unique words or sentences (words are repeated in sentences) and the Column2 is a numeric value next to each (say votes). I am trying to get a list of unique words from Column1 and then the sum of values (votes) from Column2 when the word was present either on its own or in a sentence.

Here is a sample of the data I am working with in Google Sheets:

```
Term           Votes
apple          20
apple eat      100
orange         30
orange rules   40
rule why       50
```

This is what the end result looks like:

```
Word    Votes
apple   120
eat     100
orange  70
rules   40
rule    50
why     50
```

The way I am doing it now is quite long and I am not sure if this is the best solution.

Here's my solution:

1. `JOIN` values in Column1 using a delimiter " " and then `SPLIT` them using the same delimiter and then `TRANSPOSE` them into a column all in one step. This way I have a list of all the words used in Column1 in say Column3.
2. In Column4 pull out all the `UNIQUE` values and then do a `COUNTIF` for the unique values from Column3. This way I am able to get the frequency of each unique word by referencing to the lsit of all words.
3. In order to get the sum of Votes I have to `TRANSPOSE` Column4 and then `QUERY` Column1 and Column2 by using dynamic text in the formula. The formula looks like `=QUERY(Column1:Column2, "SELECT SUM(Column2) WHERE Column1 CONTAINS '" & referenceToUniqueWord & "'", 1)`. The reason I have to transpose first is because the query formula outputs 2 cells of data ie Text: sumColumn1 and Number: 'sum of votes'. Since for one cell of unique word I get two cells of data I am not able to drag the formula down and hence I have to do it horizontally.
4. I finally get three rows of data after the last step:
   One row is just transposed Column4 (all the unique words). Second row is just the text sumColumn2 from using the `QUERY` formula. And third row is the actual sum of votes, resulting from individual `QUERY` formulae. I then transpose these rows to columns and to get my final table I `VLOOKUP` the frequency values arrived at earlier.

This approach is lengthy and prone to errors. Also doesn't work if the list is large and in the initial `JOIN` I get an error of limit 50,000 reached. Any ideas to make it better are welcome. I know this can be done much easier using Scripts but I'd prefer to have it done using only formulae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A:A, " "))="",,"♠"&SPLIT(A:A, " ")&"♦"&B:B)
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  group by Col1
  order by sum(Col2) desc 
  label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image: 0]